# Positioning on jquery boxes?

Tags: jquery, window, position, modal-dialog

first question here, so I hope im doing it right.

So, i have the script down here on my web.

I figured out how to position my modal, and then there is a white box inside it, plus a video window. I manage to position video window in the mid of the white one, so it looks like a boarder, exactly centered as I wanted, but I cant seen to centre this white one with the video on the back bigger one (modal?)

Can someone help me with that? Cause I don't know jquery at all, I just wanna have this modal effect.

Thank you a lot.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();



                position:fixed;  
                top:10px; left:10px; 

        $('#mask').css({'width':1000,'height':600});

        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family:verdana;
font-size:15px;
}

a {color:#333; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none}

#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:fixed; ***<--.... PS: i tried to use the absolute here, wouldnt work.>>>***
  left:1000;
  bottom:-100px;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}

#boxes #dialog {
  width:820px; 
  height:520px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}


.close{display:block; text-align:right;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<table border="0">
<tr>
<th><a href="#dialog" name="modal"><img height="180" width="300" src="http://www.youtube.com"></a>youtube</th>
<th><a href="#dialog" name="modal"><img height="180" width="300" src="http://www.youtube.com"></a>youtube</th>
<tr>
<td><a href="#dialog" name="modal"><img height="180" width="300" src="http://www.youtube.com"></a></td>
<td><a href="#dialog" name="modal"><img height="180" width="300" src="http://www.youtube.com"></a></td>
</tr>

</table>


</ul>

<div style="font-size:10px;color:#ccc" ></div>


<div id="boxes">

<div id="dialog" class="window" > 
<a href="#" class="close"> Close [X]</a><br />
<iframe  id="youtube" width="820" height="517" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VOayJ-QxfL4&hl" frameborder= "0" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:10px;bottom10px;"></iframe>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, After a time without trying anything,

I found this code:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'putherethesourceofyourvideo'
```

was the only thing that worked for me!